# Are there any security concerns or reasons not to publish code used in a web application

Tags: cloud, websecurity

I'm about to create my first web application. I would like to make everything open source but I wasn't sure if that was generally considered to be a bad idea. My plan was to not publish any credentials (e.g. I would load a non-published config file or environment variable), but I wasn't sure if just allowing people to dissect the running code was a security concern in itself. Are there parts of the application I shouldn't share? Is this dependent on the library being used? I don't have any concerns about the database I am working with being made public. My biggest concern is an attack on the machine (which I was planning on cloud hosting).

Not sure if it matters but I was thinking of creating a .Net web application and hosting on AWS with a sqlite database. Haven't figured out how to manage user identification, rate limiting yet ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properly made web applications that follow all of the appropriate best practices can be made public without a problem. A perfect example of this is WordPress.
As you mentioned, any private information (passwords, DB info, salt for hashing, config, etc.) should not be included in the repo - even if it is private. However, in many cases public repos provide example configuration files.

If you are using AWS, consider [Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) and [Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) for handling your configuration and secrets and as long as you follow the [Well Architected Framework](https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/well-architected/?wa-lens-whitepapers.sort-by=item.additionalFields.sortDate&wa-lens-whitepapers.sort-order=desc) your application will be secure from a Cloud Standpoint.
User identity management can be achieved through [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/).

If your application is an API, I highly recommend looking into [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) (with which you will find rate-limiting easy). If not, you could build rate limiting on top of an [Application Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/application-load-balancer/), or just build it into your software.